# integrals in terms of gamma function

Tags: recurrence-relations, gamma-function

$\displaystyle I_1 = \int^1_0 \sqrt[3]{\log( x)}\,dx$

I am trying to write this in terms of gamma functions.

After I substitute

$\displaystyle y = \log( x)$ , $x = e^y$ , $dx = e^y dy$

Then,

$\displaystyle  I_1 = \int^1_0 e^yy^{\frac{1}{2}}\,dy$

but the upper limit isn't infinite.
Can anyone please explain or help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limits are not correct.  With $y=\log(x)$, note that when $x\to 0^+$, $y\to -\infty$ and when $x=1$, $y=0$.  With that substitution we find that

$$\int_0^1 \log^{1/3}(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 y^{1/3}e^y\,dy$$

A slightly more direct substitution is to let $x=e^{-y}$ so that as $x\to 0^+$, $y\to \infty$, and for $x=1$, $y=0$, and $dx=-e^{-y}\,dy$.

Then, we can write

$$\int_0^1 \log^{1/3}(x)\,dx=-\int_0^\infty (y)^{1/3}e^{-y}\,dy=-\Gamma(4/3)$$